# Store output text in array list and display it in a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to build my first app for Android and I encountered a problem.

I want to store the output text in an arrayList and the display it in a listView that this listView is on another page.

MainActivity class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    final RadioButton radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
    final RadioButton radioButton3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
    final RadioButton radioButton4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
    final TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ArrayList<String> addArray = new ArrayList<String>();
            TextView textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

            String getInput = textView3.getText().toString();

            if(addArray.contains(getInput)){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Password already exists!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if (getInput==null){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Input field is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                addArray.add(getInput);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,addArray);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3)).setText("");
            }

            Snackbar.make(view, "Password saved!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```

At this point my code runs with no errors. But I want the listView to be in another activity named: `saved_passwords`. When I edit this

`ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,addArray);`

to this:

`ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(saved_passwords, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,addArray);`

my code won't run. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: what is `saved_passwords` in your ArrayAdapter initialization code??

Comment: And if you want your `Listview` in another activity then you have to pass the `addArray` to another activity when calling it and initialize your listView and adapter in that particular activity.

Comment: Make `addArray` public static put it in a another class such that you can access it form all Activities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the `ArrayList` when you start the SavedPassword activity, like below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
            SavedPasswordActivity.class);
data.putStringArrayList("SavedPassword",
            addArray);
intent.putExtras(data);
startActivity(intent);
```

And inside `onCreate` method of your SavedPasswordActivity you have to initialize the `ListView` something like below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_saved_password);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ArrayList<String> addArray getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("SavedPassword");
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,addArray);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And yeah don't forget to include a `ListView` inside you `activity_saved_password.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you give, you are passing the context of an activity correctly.  In the second the problem is that's not how you reference another activities context, but more importantly, you don't have access to the context of `saved_passwords` yet.  The activity is not open.

I would recommend you pass your `Listview` `addArray` to the other activity as @himanshu1496 suggested. Then you'll be able to make the following call without any errors from `saved_passwords`.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(saved_passwords.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,addArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

The **simplest way** to do it is create another class which contains your `ArrayList` which has to be `public static` like

```
public class MyClass {

    public static ArrayList<String> addArray;
}
```

Then you could add items to your `ArrayList` in your **MainActivity** as

```
MyClass.addArray.add("item");
```

And now you could also access the same `ArrayList` form your **saved_passwords** activity as

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(saved_passwords.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,MyClass.addArray);
```

I hope this was helpful.